# Optimize SQLite Query using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I am trying to optimize my query which uses GROUP BY. But can't it takes too long time.

I have a virtual table which contains 3 columns:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE GoiWordsWithSeq
USING FTS5(idseq,sid,body);
```

I want the group to be just as the query below, but it just takes a bit too long to run.
For example I tried this first which works pretty good but still I wonder if I can make it faster:

```
select 
GROUP_CONCAT(body), sid
from GoiWordsWithSeq
GROUP BY sid
HAVING sid IN (
select sid from GoiWordsWithSeq
where GoiWordsWithSeq.body match 'awesome'
)
```

Then:

```
  select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(body), GoiWordsWithSeq.sid
    from GoiWordsWithSeq
    inner join  (
    select sid from GoiWordsWithSeq
    where GoiWordsWithSeq.body match 'awesome'
    ) GoiMatch ON GoiMatch.sid = GoiWordsWithSeq.sid 

    GROUP BY GoiWordsWithSeq.sid
```

But it still takes long time to query. I'm trying to use JOIN because I heard it is usually faster but can't really succed. Any advice would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you choose to set the condition in the `HAVING` clause?
With your code the condition is checked after all the aggregations are finished.
Your condition does not involve any aggregated column so there is no reason to use it in the `HAVING` clause.
It would make more sense to set it in a `WHERE` clause so the dataset is filtered and then `GROUP BY` is applied for aggregation:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(body), sid
FROM GoiWordsWithSeq
WHERE sid IN (
  SELECT sid FROM GoiWordsWithSeq
  WHERE body MATCH 'awesome'
)
GROUP BY sid
```

You could also try `EXISTS` which sometimes performs better:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(g.body), g.sid
FROM GoiWordsWithSeq g
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM GoiWordsWithSeq
  WHERE sid = g.sid AND body MATCH 'awesome'
)
GROUP BY g.sid
```

Comment: "Why did you choose to set the condition in the HAVING clause?" This I don't know... Thank you first query you showed me (with just not doing the HAVING) solved it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `having` clause:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(body), sid
from GoiWordsWithSeq
GROUP BY sid
having sum( GoiWordsWithSeq.body match 'awesome' ) > 0;
```

If `match` doesn't work in `having`, I would suggeset:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(body), sid
from (select g.*, (GoiWordsWithSeq.body match 'awesome') as flag
      from GoiWordsWithSeq
     ) g
group sid
having sum( flag ) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't get match work inside having sum() interesting enough though, if I do use LIKE it works pretty fast. Although it seems like FTS5 doesn't support match here.

Comment: @mpj . . . I was wondering if that would work.  I added an alternative.  How is the performance on that?